# Put VMWare guest and computer in ethernet network in same subnet

Tags: networking, vmware

I have

- computer A (has WIFI) (Windows 10)
- computer B connected to A with ethernet cable (Manjaro)
- VM on computer A (Manjaro on VMWare Workstation 15)

I want VM and computer B to communicate with each other. Right now I have only A <-> B and A <-> VM communication.

When network settings are:

- NAT - VM is available from host on "Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1".
- Bridged - VM is available from host on "Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi".

B communicates with A on "Ethernet adapter Ethernet".

What options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect two computers to each other via ethernet cable, you must use a crossover type cable and manually assign IP addresses. It is far easier to use a switch between both A and B or plug both computers into your router then use DHCP & Bridging on vmware, A and B.

Comment: Thanks you for response. If ICS is enabled for Ethernet it receives 192.168.137.x IP while vm is in 192.168.0.x subnet. If i assign IP addresses manually computer be does not have internet Connection.

Comment: And if i don't use ICS computer B has 169.254.x.x ip assigned.

Comment: Never use internet connection sharing for anything, ever. It's one of the worst inventions by microsoft. Please buy a small switch.

Comment: I can't plug switch and router though (my pcs and router are in different rooms). Is there some way to utilize usb wifi and give internet access through switch to computer B?

Comment: Use homeplug/powerline adapters to join the computers to the switch.

Comment: Wow... Haven't heard about homeplug. It seems it will solve my problems. :) Thank you for help.